# DIfference between Thumbnail and GeoTIFF Images in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to build a Deep Learning model that takes Satellite Image as Input and uses a few demographics parameter as output.

I am new to Google Earth Engine, so I was checking different ways to export the data.
I can export it as a GeoTIFF Image or a Thumbnail. Since I just need the RGB bands of the Image, will it make any difference if I use a thumbnail. 
For eg: Will I lose any information that might be helpful for the model to learn?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between `getThumbURL` and export operations in Earth Engine is that export operations are batch tasks — they are allowed to run longer, whereas ‘thumbnails’ are only suitable for images that are small and fast to compute. You'll get the same *content* whichever method you use.

You will need to specify `format: 'geotiff'` to get a GeoTIFF result, though.